# Different kind of M13 primer

Tags: primer

I m looking for universal primers M13. I found different version. For instance :

- M13 (-21) Forward TGTAAAACGACGGCCAGT
- M13 (-40) GTTTTCCCAGTCACGAC

What's the meaning of (-21) and (-40 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dates back to the 1980's when these M13 primers were first cloned.

[Heidecker G, Messing J, Gronenborn B. 1980. A versatile primer for DNA sequencing in the M13mp2 cloning system. Gene 10(1):69-73.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6250947)

In this paper, they discuss the construction of a primer for sequencing of the [M13mp2 phage vector](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/L08818). An EcoRI/AluI digest releases a 92 bp fragment from a portion of the lac operon. This fragment contains what are now called the M13 forward -21 and -40 primers. I do not know who first named these primers but, counting from the centre of the EcoRI palindrome, I think it's clear where these names came from:

[image]